# Is it possible to see which questions I've downvoted?

Tags: support, voting, down-votes

Is it possible to see which posts I've downvoted?

I mean, I can see what is giving me reputation, and which questions I'm upvoting, but I couldn't find anywhere if we can see the downvotes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to your profile page, to the Activity tab.

In the sub-tabs, there is a votes tab (only visible to yourself and moderators), which can be filtered to downvotes.

In one link:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/4070469/mauker?tab=votes&sort=downvote

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Just open the `downvotes` tab under the `votes` in your profile:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=votes&sort=downvote